# Cómo mantener los cambios de extensiones en Notebook de Jupyter

Tags: jupyter, ipython

Busco **mantener los cambios de las extensiones** de un notebook de jupyter, para exportar con `nbconvert`.

Extensiones de jupyter:

- codefolding
- python markdown
- runtools

Uso anaconda:

- Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda custom (x86_64)
- conda 4.2.9
- anaconda Command line client (version 1.4.0)

Con el archivo `ipython_nbconvert_config.py` en el mismo directorio del notebook (y también `jupyter_nbconvert_config.py` ya que dudaba entre ambos) cuyo contenido, siguiendo [este ISSUE](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/issues/198), es:

```
from IPython.utils.path import get_ipython_dir
import os
import sys

ipythondir = get_ipython_dir()
extensions = os.path.join(ipythondir,'extensions') 
sys.path.append( extensions )

c = get_config()
c.Exporter.template_path = [os.path.join(ipythondir,'templates') ]
c.Exporter.template_file = 'hide_input_output.tpl'

c.Exporter.preprocessors = ['codefolding.CodeFoldingPreprocessor', 'pymdpreprocessor.PyMarkdownPreprocessor' ]
c.Exporter.postprocessors = ['embed.EmbedPostProcessor']
c.NbConvertApp.postprocessor = ['embed.EmbedPostProcessor']
```

Pero al hacer `jupyter nbconvert --to html analysis.ipynb`, me devuelve el siguiente traceback:

```
/Users/mmngreco/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/utils/path.py:258: UserWarning: get_ipython_dir has moved to the IPython.paths module
  warn("get_ipython_dir has moved to the IPython.paths module")
[NbConvertApp] WARNING | Config option `postprocessor` not recognized by `NbConvertApp`.  Did you mean `postprocessor_class`?
[NbConvertApp] WARNING | Config option `postprocessor` not recognized by `NbConvertApp`.  Did you mean `postprocessor_class`?
[NbConvertApp] WARNING | Config option `postprocessors` not recognized by `HTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `default_preprocessors, preprocessors`?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mmngreco/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-nbconvert", line 6, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/mmngreco/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mmngreco/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 596, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/Users/mmngreco/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 293, in start
    self.convert_notebooks()
  File "/Users/mmngreco/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 447, in convert_notebooks
    self.exporter = cls(config=self.config)
  File "/Users/mmngreco/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 151, in __init__
    super(TemplateExporter, self).__init__(config=config, **kw)
  File "/Users/mmngreco/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 101, in __init__
    self._init_preprocessors()
  File "/Users/mmngreco/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 250, in _init_preprocessors
    self.register_preprocessor(preprocessor, enabled=True)
  File "/Users/mmngreco/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 211, in register_preprocessor
    preprocessor_cls = import_item(preprocessor)
  File "/Users/mmngreco/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipython_genutils/importstring.py", line 31, in import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
ImportError: No module named 'codefolding'
```

Comment: Prueba a cambiar `'codefolding.CodeFoldingPreprocessor'` por `'jupyter_contrib_nbextensions.nbconvert_support.CodeFoldingPreprocessor'`

Comment: muchas gracias @kikocorreoso, perdón por la tardanza. El caso es que ahora, me han dejado de funcionar otros paquetes y no puedo comprobar si funciona hasta que no lo resuelva. :-/